# Multiply row with upper row in a column of DataFrame (Python)

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a dataframe below and I want to add another column called "CUMULATIVE". To get the value of that column you need to just multiply [DAILY]row(x) * [DAILY]row(x-1). In excel it is pretty simple, because you only need to paste formula "=A2*A1" in the the second row and just drag it down. But it is getting hard for me to repeat it in python. Do you have any ideas how to do it ?

I used the below line but it is not correct, because because it multiplicates with each above rows, instead of with just 2 rows nearby.

```
df['cumprod'] = df.groupby('TICKER')['MNOZNIK_DZIENNY'].cumprod()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I came up with the solution few seconds after I published my question :) Using **SHIFT** in Python should do the job, but if you have other possibilites in mind be free to type!